# Call Javascript validation functional from the Submit button

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and any help would be appreciated.

I am getting an error saying not a formValidation is not a function and in the console I am seeing the following:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at portfolio/js/script.js:12:23

Following is the package structure:

```
Portfolio
  js
    script.js
    formValidation.js
index.html
```

I have added script.js to my html page

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

FormValidation.js (exporting it)

```
var FormValidation = function () {

    var name = document.forms["contact"]["name"].value;

    function nameValidation(name) {

        if(name=="") {
            alert("Enter name, required");
            return false;
        }else if(name==[0-9]) {
            alert("Only alphabets");
        }

        return true;
    }

    nameValidation(name);
};

module.exports = FormValidation;
```

script.js (calling formValidation.js)

```
'use strict';

var FormValidation = require("./formValidation");
```

index.html

```
<form name="contact" action="#" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME"></br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required></br>
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="PHONE-NUMBER"></br> 
 <input type="text-box" name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE"></br>
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="return FormValidation()"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane">Submit</i></button></br>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the error? Why can't I call FormValidation() from the html page on onclick event?

Comment: You haven't loaded `require.js`, so there's no function `require()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do require like that without a tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

You would have to add another script like this to your html file. If you were using node.js(backend), then require would work with no problem, but with the client side you need a tool like browserify.

Here is the browserify-less solution:

```
<script src="js/formValidation.js"></script>
```

Comment: is browserify same as webpack? So I need to compress it in an output file script.min.js to make my above program work? The solution you suggested worked, thanks.

Comment: I think they are similar tools because they both bundle up files into other files. But Browserify seems to rely on other tools like gulp/grunt to do its tasks more efficiently while webpack does the job by itself. Webpack is a bit harder to set up.